# overload operator = in c#

Tags: operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload operator = in c#?

when i call =, i just want to copy properties, rather than making the left hand reference to refer another instance.

Comment: On a related note: http://freeworld.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html.

Comment: @Nathan: that's a masterpiece. Pretty good advice there.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for value type semantics. Aren't structs better for you in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is [no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> Note that the assignment operator itself (=) cannot be overloaded. An assignment always performs a simple bit-wise copy of a value into a variable.

And even if it was possible, I wouldn't recommend it.  Nobody who reads the code is going to think that there's ANY possibility that the assignment operator's been overloaded.  A method to copy the object will be much clearer.

Comment: When I read the title of the question I was sincerely hoping this was the answer. Thankfully this isn't yet another way to wreak havoc in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload the `=` operator. Furthermore, what you are trying to do would entirely change the operator's semantics, so in other words is a bad idea.

If you want to provide copy semantics, provide a `Clone()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a .CopyProperties(ByVal yourObject As YourObject) method in the object?

Are you using a built-in object?

Answer (score 0):

We can Overload = operator but not directly.

```
using System;
class Over
{
    private int a;
    public Over(int a )
    {   
        this.a = a;
    }

public int A { get => a; }

    public static implicit operator int(Over obj)
    {
        return obj.A;
    }
}
class yo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Over over = new Over(10);
        int a = over;
    }
}
```

Here when you call that operator overloading method , it is calling = operator itself to convert that to int. You cannot directly overload "=" but this way of code means the same.